# Angular data flow

Tags: angular

I'm working on an angular application where a parent passes a child component a model and the child has a form that can update this model.

`<child-component [model]="model"></child-component>`

Since the parent passes the model object reference, if the child updates model.someProperty, parent.model will also be updated because it's the same object.

Is this bad practice? To use one-way binding but then update a property of the @Input from the child?

Other approaches I've considered are using two-way binding or using two-way binding and creating a new model object rather than updating the original when the child makes changes.

Which of these approaches is preferred? (The child-component has a form that updates the model on field change, so creating a new model object everytime something changes seems a little excessive...)

Comment: This subject is a source of constant opinionated debates.  Every framework treats these kinds of problems in a different way;  ReactJs, for example, treats everything as immutable, while Angular generally does not.  Ultimately, this is why these frameworks are called "opinionated frameworks", and answers here will be just as opinionated, which doesn't work well for this site's format.